# DotNetNuke module saves module settings without using sql server

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have found two modules that save their module specific settings without using sql server.

After the module finish installing the installation log shows that there was no sql provider scripts and when I check the DNN database tables there is no new table created.

One of the modules in question is a free module to create a popup window.
http://www.codingstaff.com/products/dotnetnuke-modules/free-dnn-pop-up

So my question is: Is there any form of storage inside DotNetNuke that a module can use to persist their settings other than SQL Server?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules can store their settings in ModuleSettings or TabModuleSettings tables that are part of the DNN installation.

But to answer your question, there is no other form of persisting settings in DotNetNuke besides using sql.

Comment: Thanks. I went back to look into the Module Settings table and there was the setting.